# LVM writecache not fully emptying

Tags: lvm, cache

I'm struggling with an LVM issue. I have a writecache attached to an existing LV. I've been polling the LV as well as the writecache with

> lvs -o+writecache_total_blocks,writecache_free_blocks

but no matter how long I wait, the free blocks never reach the total blocks, almost as if the cache isn't emptying out completely after being written to. It only reaches about half the total blocks number, then just sits there.

Is this expected behavior, or is my cache not flushing properly after being written to?

Comment: You can run `sync` few time, and see if the second time is much quicker (else: probably some processes are writing often to disk). `vmstat` may confirm it.

Answer (score 4):

If you used the `lvconvert --type writecache` (as opposed to `--type cache`), then the cache writeback works in a low/high watermark system: writeback starts when the cache usage reaches the high watermark (some quick googling indicates this might be 50%), and stops when it reaches the low watermark (default might be 45%). Your experience would seem to fit within the expected default behavior.

If you want the cache to become completely empty on writeback, you might want to set the low watermark to 0%. That would be the option `--cachesettings 'low_watermark=0'` when creating the cache. Or you might want to set `--cachesettings 'cleaner=1'` which would gradually flush all data from the cache, just like how `lvconvert --splitcache` or `lvconvert --uncache` would do it when removing the cache from the LV. There are other tunable settings; for more details, see the `lvmcache(7)` man page.

If you haven't set any `--cachesettings` options, the writecache will work using kernel built-in defaults. Any customized cache settings can be verified with `lvs -o +cache_settings`: if the cache uses kernel defaults, the `CacheSettings` column will be blank.

Comment: LVM is flexible enough to allow setting cache settings on the fly. Just run `lvchange --cachesettings 'low_watermark=0' myvg/mylv` – and maybe set `pause_writeback` and `autocommit_time`, too? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771886/20336 for a longer example.